# To retrive all Event deatils (Where,Description,etc) in Google calendar using Google-API-Java-Client in android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have been trying to get Event details like Location details,Description,start time and end time etc of the event in Google calendar using Google-API-Java-Client in android.

I am using the following sample code

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg%2Fcalendar-v2-atom-android-sample

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your question only in the scope of When.
This is my solution referenced from calendar-android-sample:

```
    List<EventEntry> events; //Don't forget to initialize
    //Get CalendarEntry from somewhere
    CalendarEntry calendar = getCalendar(); //this my function. Create your own.

    CalendarUrl eventUrl =
        new CalendarUrl(calendar.getEventFeedLink());
    // page through results
    while (true) {
      EventFeed eventFeed = client.eventFeed().list().execute(eventUrl);
      if (eventFeed.events != null) {
        events.addAll(eventFeed.events);
      }
      String nextLink = eventFeed.getNextLink();
      if (nextLink == null) {
        break;
      }
    }
    int numEvents = events.size();
    When[] times = new When[numEvents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numEvents; i++) {
      times[i] = events.get(i).when; //here you can get all events time. Manipulate as you wish.
    }
```